# Extract and Reuse elements as list in JMeter

Tags: automated-testing, jmeter, test-strategy

```
[{
    elem1: value,
    elem2: value
},
{
    elem1: value,
    elem2: value
}]
```

I want to be able to extract all `elem2` value based on a `regex` condition on `elem1` value from a `JSON` response.

I understand, that I can do this through Regex Extractor.

In doing that I want to save the elem2 values as some sort of collection (`CSV` file perhaps), that I could use as an input for another call later on in the test.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51284957/jmeter-extract-all-values-from-regular-expression-and-store-in-a-csv) shows the way to create the csv file.

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37749223/jmeter-regex-extracting-the-exact-value-from-json-reponse-code) shows how to extract a value based on another value